# JS code for multiple "Show more" buttons in html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

I've been trying to use multiple "Show more" buttons on an html based web app. I've tried different JS functions for this purpose, but I'm going wrong somewhere.
Currently, only one "Show more" is working.
My code is below.  Kindly help me with the correct solution for this code.

```js
function myFunction6() {
  var dots = document.getElementById("dots6");
  var moreText = document.getElementById("more6");
  var btnText = document.getElementById("button6");
  //   var btnText1 = document.getElementById("button6");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Show more";
    // btnText1.innerHTML = "Show more"; 
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Show less";
    // btnText1.innerHTML = "Show less"; 
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```css
#button6 {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

#button6:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

#more6 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="card6">
  <p>Before show more 1</p>
  <span id="dots6"></span>

  <span id="more6">
                <p>
                   After Show more 1
                </p>
            </span>
  <p><button onclick="myFunction6()" id="button6">Show more</button></p>

</div>


<div class="card6">
  <p> Before Show more</p>
  <span id="dots6"></span>

  <span id="more6">
                <p>
                  After show mor
                </p>
            </span>

  <p><button onclick="myFunction6()" id="button6">Show more</button></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you use jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that you have few elements with the same id on the page and `document.getElementById` gets the first entry. That is why only the first block is getting expanded/collapsed no matter what button you click.

I have modified your code to get the parent `.card6` container when the button is clicked.
And then you can use `querySelector` method to get an element with a specific id inside that container.

```js
function myFunction6(event) {
  var card = event.target.closest(".card6");
  var dots = card.querySelector("#dots6");
  var moreText = card.querySelector("#more6");
  var btnText = card.querySelector("#button6");
  //   var btnText1 = document.getElementById("button6");

  if (dots.style.display === "none") {
    dots.style.display = "inline";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Show more";
    // btnText1.innerHTML = "Show more"; 
    moreText.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    dots.style.display = "none";
    btnText.innerHTML = "Show less";
    // btnText1.innerHTML = "Show less"; 
    moreText.style.display = "inline";
  }
}
```

```css
#button6 {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
}

#button6:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

#more6 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="card6">
  <p>Before show more 1</p>
  <span id="dots6"></span>

  <span id="more6">
                <p>
                   After Show more 1
                </p>
            </span>
  <p><button onclick="myFunction6(event)" id="button6">Show more</button></p>

</div>


<div class="card6">
  <p> Before Show more</p>
  <span id="dots6"></span>

  <span id="more6">
                <p>
                  After show mor
                </p>
            </span>

  <p><button onclick="myFunction6(event)" id="button6">Show more</button></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

id's have to be unique for all components. when you have same id for multiple elements and call `getById`, JS will return only the first element.. you should never give the same id to multiple elements. what you can do is go through the event to get your target elements. i.e

```
function myFunction6(event) {
  let btnText = event.target; // element that was clicked
  let parent = btnText.parentElement; // its parent
  let siblings = parent.children; // collection of siblings
  var dots = siblings[1]; // 2nd element in the parent container
  var moreText = siblings[2]; // 3rd element in the parent container
  //   var btnText1 = document.getElementById("button6");

  ...

}
```

This keeps the function dynamic going after the element that is clicked.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion and solution